# NSData dataWithContentsOfURL issue

Tags: ios4

I have a string with url.Please take a look at the following code.I am not getting what's the error.Getting an exception like :

### Exception :

```
[NSCFString isFileURL]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b69700
2011-04-22 00:16:30.520 SC.Pandit[15098:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught           

exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSCFString isFileURL]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b69700'
```

### My Code :

```
NSURL *url =(NSURL *) imageURL;
NSLog(@"%@",url);
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worries me;

```
NSURL *url =(NSURL *) imageURL;
```

Looks like you are maybe casting a string to a NSURL? How is imageURL defined?

If so, don't do that, do it properly with something like;

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:imageURL];
```

Of course if imageURL is not NSString, then you will need to get it into that to start with.

But could you give an example of what your URL actually looks like, that could be the issue.

Comment: imageURL and imageName are NSString.this is how i concate them :imageURL=@"http://localhost:85/2/";
  imageURL=[imageURL stringByAppendingString:imageName]; and the imageURL my code producing is : http://localhost:85/2/man_%20leonardo_di_caprio.jpg as a string.

Comment: i just tried with your code.i am getting no exception but the image is not showing.i think there are some space issue with the image name.how can i avoid them?